# A sufficient condition for a composition of functions to be measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{T},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and $(E,\mathcal{E})$, $(F,\mathcal{F})$ be two measurable spaces. Let $X,Y$ be two random variables on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ with the same laws, and $\phi:E\longrightarrow F$ a function such that $\phi(X)$ is measurable ($\phi$ itself is not assumed to be measurable).

**Questions:** Is $\phi(Y)$ measurable? If so, are $\phi(X)$ and $\phi(Y)$ equal in law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general not. All $\sigma$-algebras in the following should be taken to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Suppose that $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $\mathbb P$ is a Dirac at $\{0\}$ so that $\mathbb P((0,1]) = 0$. Then, let $X(\omega) = 0$ and $Y(\omega) = \omega$. Clearly the laws of $X$ and $Y$ are both Diracs at zero.

Now choose $\phi : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a non-measurable function. Of course
$(\phi \circ X)(\omega) = \phi(0)$, which is constant and hence measurable. On the other hand, $(\phi \circ Y)(\omega) = \phi(\omega)$, which by assumption is not measurable.